how to select and highlight texts from pdf in pyqt5/pyqt6/pyside6?
I am developing a Python desktop application using PyQt6 where I need to render the pdf in the app. I need to select and highlight the texts from the rendered pdf. After that I need to implement drag and drop functionality for these texts. First, I created the pdfview2.ui file and converted it into pdfview2.py file. To handle the required functionality, I've created pdfviewController.py separately.
Currently I'm using QPdfView and MuPDF for pdf rendering and selecting and highlighting the texts from the PDF. However, I'm able to render the pdf smoothly using QPdfView widget but not able to select the text using mouse and its co-ordinates.
I have tried the rendering pdf in QPdfView and it is successfully rendering. After that I need to select the texts, highlight it with dedicated pushbuttons and implement the drag and drop the functionality for it. Currently I am not able to select the text from the pdf as pdf pages are rendering as Images. If I try to extract the texts first (using MuPDF) and then render it, the pdf will no longer remain in it's original format. I need to select + highlight the text from the pdf after rendering it into it's original format. Consider the scenario where we generally open the PDFs in Microsoft Edge or Adobe Acrobat where they will render the PDF as it is and allowed us to select the pdf text and highlight it.
Does anyone has answer to this?? How can i do this smoothly??
Below is the relevant part of the code -->>
`import sys
import os
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QScrollArea, QGraphicsRectItem,QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QToolBar, QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QSize, QMimeData, QPoint, QRectF, QSizeF, QPointF
from PyQt6.QtGui import QColor, QDrag, QPainter, QPen, QBrush, QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt6.QtPdfWidgets import QPdfView
from PyQt6.QtPdf import QPdfDocument
from Views.pdfview2 import Ui_Pdfviewpane  # Assuming you have this setup


class PDFViewController(QMainWindow, Ui_Pdfviewpane):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pdfDocument = QPdfDocument(self)
        self.pdfView.setDocument(self.pdfDocument)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.upload_file)

        self.add_toolbar()c
        # Initialize highlight color
        self.highlight_color = QColor("yellow")

        self.pdfView.setPageMode(QPdfView.PageMode.SinglePage)

        # Initialize selection variables
        self.selection_start = None
        self.selection_end = None
        self.current_selection_rect = None
        self.highlighted_rects = []

        # Initialize MuPDF document
        self.mupdf_document = None

        # Set up the text cursor
        self.pdfView.setCursor(Qt.CursorShape.IBeamCursor)

        # Connect mouse events to custom handlers
        self.pdfView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.pdfView.viewport().setMouseTracking(True)

    def add_toolbar(self):
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")
        navtb.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))

        upload_file_btn = QPushButton("Upload File")
        navtb.addWidget(upload_file_btn)
        upload_file_btn.clicked.connect(self.upload_file)

        highlight_yellow_btn = QPushButton("Highlight Yellow")
        navtb.addWidget(highlight_yellow_btn)
        highlight_yellow_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_highlight_color('yellow'))

        highlight_green_btn = QPushButton("Highlight Green")
        navtb.addWidget(highlight_green_btn)
        highlight_green_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_highlight_color('green'))

        highlight_blue_btn = QPushButton("Highlight Blue")
        navtb.addWidget(highlight_blue_btn)
        highlight_blue_btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.set_highlight_color('blue'))

        self.addToolBar(navtb)

    def set_highlight_color(self, color):
        self.highlight_color = QColor(color)

    def upload_file(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Option.ReadOnly
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', os.getenv('HOME'), options=options)
        if file_path:
            print(f"Selected file: {file_path}")
            file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1].lower()
            if file_extension == '.pdf':
                self.render_pdf(file_path)
                self.load_mupdf_document(file_path)
            else:
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Extension Not Supported", f"The file extension '{file_extension}' is not supported.")
        else:
            print("No file selected")

    def render_pdf(self, file_path):
        try:
            self.pdfDocument.load(file_path)
            print(f"PDF rendered successfully: {file_path}")
            self.pdfView.setPageMode(QPdfView.PageMode.MultiPage)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to render PDF: {e}")
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"Failed to render PDF: {e}")

    def load_mupdf_document(self, file_path):
        try:
            self.mupdf_document = fitz.open(file_path)
            print(f"MuPDF document loaded successfully: {file_path}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to load MuPDF document: {e}")
            QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", f"Failed to load MuPDF document: {e}")

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.pdfView.viewport():
            if event.type() == event.Type.MouseButtonPress:
                return self.mousePressEvent(event)
            elif event.type() == event.Type.MouseMove:
                return self.mouseMoveEvent(event)
            elif event.type() == event.Type.MouseButtonRelease:
                return self.mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.selection_start = event.pos()
            self.selection_end = None
            self.current_selection_rect = QRectF(self.selection_start, QSize())
            self.pdfView.viewport().update()
            return True
        return False

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.selection_end = event.pos()
            self.current_selection_rect = QRectF(self.selection_start, self.selection_end).normalized()
            self.pdfView.viewport().update()
            return True
        return False

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            self.finalize_selection()
            return True
        return False

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.pdfView.viewport())
        if self.current_selection_rect:
            pen = QPen(QColor(0, 0, 255, 100), 2, Qt.PenStyle.DashLine)
            brush = QBrush(QColor(255, 255, 0, 50))
            painter.setPen(pen)
            painter.setBrush(brush)
            painter.drawRect(self.current_selection_rect)
        super().paintEvent(event)

    def finalize_selection(self):
        if self.selection_start and self.selection_end:
            selection_rect = QRectF(self.selection_start, self.selection_end).normalized()
            highlight_rect = QGraphicsRectItem(selection_rect)
            highlight_rect.setBrush(QColor(255, 255, 0, 100))  # semi-transparent yellow
            self.highlighted_rects.append(highlight_rect)
            self.pdfView.viewport().update()

            if self.mupdf_document:
                page = self.mupdf_document.load_page(0)  # Load the first page for simplicity
                text = page.get_text("text", clip=fitz.Rect(selection_rect.left(),                   selection_rect.top(), selection_rect.right(), selection_rect.bottom()))
                print("Selected text:", text.strip())
                self.drag_text(text.strip())

    def drag_text(self, text):
        drag = QDrag(self)
        mime_data = QMimeData()
        mime_data.setText(text)
        drag.setMimeData(mime_data)
        drag.exec_(Qt.DropAction.CopyAction)
`



Right now the QtPdf module doesn't directly provide interactive selection (the QML based viewer seem to partially support it, at least since 6.6.1). Note that the PDF module is relatively new and still a partial work in progress (its docs are also partially incomplete). In any case, you can get that functionality by subclassing QPdfView and create selections on your own by using its getSelection() function and the bounds() of the returned QPdfSelection object (if you want to highlight it).

Thanks @musicamante for your valuable suggestion. I tried subclassing QPdfView and created selections by overriding default mouse events and its QGetSelection() method but still no luck. Does any other language support this smooth pdf text selection??

What do you mean by "no luck"? getSelection() (please use correct names, there's no such thing as "QGetSelection") returns a QPdfSelection, you have to draw its contents based on its bounds() as already written. And Qt is not a language, it's a toolkit.

I mistakenly placed "Get"  instead of "Pdf", I know it should be "QPdfSelection" and not "QGetSelection". I know Qt is not language rather it's a tool. My question was on different context. Anyway Thanks for your advice.

Ok, but we still don't know what you mean by "no luck". How did you implement that? What problems did you get? Please [edit] your question with a [mre] based on your attempts with getSelection() and explain why/what doesn't work for you.
